# How to load an json api in cayley graph db

Tags: python, json, cayley

I have various data located within various data sources like Json ,various apis etc,.Now there is requirement to collate all these data and push it into cayley graph data base.
this will eventually act as an input for a chatbot framework. i am currently not aware of how collate existing data and push it into cayley graph n retrieve cayley graph database.
help needed …
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cayley cannot import JSON data directly by design.

The main reason is that it has no way of knowing which values in JSON are node IDs and which are regular string values.

However, it supports [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) format which is the same as regular JSON but includes some additional annotations. These annotations help to solve an uncertainity I mentioned.

I suggest checking JSON-LD [Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/) examples first and then [schema.org](https://schema.org/) for a list of well-known object types. Note that it's also possible to define your own types. See JSON-LD documentation for details.

The last step would be to use Cayley's [HTTP API v2](https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/blob/master/docs/HTTP.md#http-methods) to import the data. Make sure to pass a correct [Content-Type](https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/blob/master/docs/api/swagger.yml#L162) header, or use Cayley client that supports JSON-LD.